# Atoi(char *p) function

Tags: c, xcode, macos

I need to convert my string into int array. so i make a loop over string, and call `int atoi(char *p)` function from `stdlib.h`, but it doesn`t working on mac (some times ago i tryed it on Windows, and it workong well). simple loop:

```
    for(p = buff; *p; p++)
    printf("%d", atoi(p));
```

whats the problem with work of this function, u think?

Comment: You mean convert each individual `char` in `buff` to an `int`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function is working perfectly fine. For instance if `buff` contains `"123"`, your code will print `123233`.

However it seems you want to just print the value of individual digits, in which case `atoi` has nothing to do with your problem. Try:

```
for(p = buff; *p; p++)
    printf("%d", *p-'0');
```

Comment: You should use `isdigit()` to check if it is really a digit before  converting it